# How do you close all webpages with a certain title?

Tags: javascript, html, reload

My [website]: http://www.zombrom.com/experiments/popular.html has an automatic re-loader and it reopens the page every time a reload happens I want to know how to close all of these websites at once here is my current code it won't open any more sites though:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  location.reload();
  window.open("http://www.zombrom.com/experiments/popular.html");
}, 1000);
```

```html
<center><b>Ready!</b>
</center>
```

Comment: Tiny Giant what is wrong again?

Comment: I'm not asking why isn't this code working!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could use `window.close()`

[window.close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close)

```
var openWindows =  [], newWindow;
setInterval(function() {
  /* Will not work with location.realod() */
  //location.reload();
  //push reference to the opened windows into an array
  newWindow = window.open("http://www.zombrom.com/experiments/popular.html");
  openWindows.push(newWindow);
}, 1000);

/* call this function when you want to close all the windows that you have opened*/
function closeAllOpenWindows(){
   openWindows.forEach(function(openWindow){
      openWindow.close();
     }
   );
}
```

Comment: How does this actually work? `location.reload();` reloads the page, all the variables are re-initialized ... Also `reload()` is like a `return`, nothing after it will be executed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice `location.reload()`.  It will not work with `location.reload()`